# problems with objectanimator and the end listener

Tags: android, canvas

I'm writing code to make a circle fall. The problem is that when I call a method that puts a piece random, it does well, but in the second turn it puts 2 pieces and in the 3 turn 3 pieces. I know that the problem appears when I put the line : `game.juegaMaquina();` inside the end listener.

The code is :

```
 public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        final int fila;
        final int columna;

        pixel_x = (int) event.getX();
        pixel_y = (int) event.getY();
        fila = getFila(pixel_y);
        columna = getColumna(pixel_x);

        if (game.tableroLleno()) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.fin_del_juego,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return true;
        }

        if (game.sePuedeColocarFicha(fila, columna) != true) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.nosepuedecolocarficha,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }

        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            if(pixel_y > 200) {
                animator.start();
                animator.setIntValues(200, getPixelFromFila(getFila(pixel_y)));
                animator.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        game.juegaMaquina();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        game.ponerJugador(fila, columna);
                        if (game.comprobarCuatro(Game.JUGADOR)) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Has ganado " + nombreFinal,
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            if (game.fin()) {
                                FragmentoDialogo dialogo = new FragmentoDialogo();
                                dialogo.show(getFragmentManager(), "Alert Dialog");
                            }
                        }
                        game.juegaMaquina();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    }
                });
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was the write in the onAnimationEnd this line :

```
animator.removeAllListeners
```